# Open Data Sets in Portable SAS

Tags: sas

I'm using SAS 9.2 portable, under windows XP in a virtualized environment, and I need to open a data set with the .sas7bdat extension.

Under another windows machine, with an installed version of SAS, I right click the data set and I open it with SAS.

Unfortunately on this machine S.AS is not installed, as only the SAS portable version is present. Thus opening with right click is not possible, and when I open it with SAS > File > Open Program .... an odd error is showed, as it is not a program but a data set.

How Can I open .sas7bdat files with portable SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use File Explorer.

From the top bar:

View > Explorer > Navigate to your files.

Yes, SAS is really counter intuitive, he seems to hate the user.

Answer (score 0):

To view a SAS dataset on a machine without a SAS licence you can use the SAS Universal viewer.
This is a JAVA app that is a free download from the SAS website.

If you have R (also free) you may be able to open and use the foriegn package to work with the data.